# Azure WebJob initializing without starting

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure WebJob that is periodically called to start and look for new blob uploads in my Azure storage.
Today the WebJob is not able to start. The status never changes from "Initializing" to Starting or Running.

The latest log shows no errors, latest entries:

```
[02/17/2016 04:22:44 > 4bf485: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
[02/17/2016 04:22:44 > 4bf485: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[02/17/2016 04:22:44 > 4bf485: INFO] Job host stopped
[02/17/2016 04:22:45 > 4bf485: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
[02/17/2016 04:22:45 > 4bf485: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
```

I tried to start the Job manually and I deleted the WebJob and re-published it via Visual Studio, both without success. The Website is also running and shows no errors (I also restarted it).

**UPDATE:**
The Website is running in free mode, but there is no traffic on the website - it is only hosting the webjob. The WebJob is running continously - I have a local program that calls the webjob periodically to keep it alive. I know this is not perfect, but it doesn't have to be perfect. This whole concept was running fine for the last 2 month.

Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: Don't run webjob on your production slot open another slot or app for them.

Comment: the Website is running in free mode, so that's not possible, but there is no traffic on the website - it is only hosting the webjob

Comment: Is your web job scheuduled or continous webjob ?

Comment: Kill your webjob exe from Kudu. yourazureurl.scm.azurewebsites.net

Comment: I'm in kudu at the WebJobs dashboard, but I can't find a way to kill the Job.

Comment: Open Process Explorer expand all processes if your webjob exe is there right click on it then click kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I had a free database as a connected resource on the website. I wasn't using this database so I didn't realize that it was deleted by Azure (or I didn't care when they told me ;-)). I removed the link in the azure portal to the database and I removed the connection string in the application settings connection string section (which seemed to cause the problem). My WebJob started running immediately after these changes.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to run a Continuous WebJob in a Free site. This is not supported because Free sites can't use the Always On feature. From the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/):

> For Continuous WebJobs to run reliably and on all instances, enable the Always On* configuration setting for the web app otherwise they can stop running when the SCM host site has been idle for too long.

Comment: that it is usually not a problem, because I have a local program that calls the webjob and brings it back running. Even when I call my WebJob directly in the browser with https://website.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/jobs it is not starting. Status is still initializing.